# laravel seems to inherit env variables

Tags: php, oauth, lumen, laravel-passport, guzzle

I have a very weird, and should-be-impossible error here. I have a Laravel project, let's call it sso, using Passport as oauth server. When i call the /oauth/token endpoint from postman it works fine. I also have a lumen + react based project as consumer app, let's call this licensing. The react frontend has a login page, asking for username+password, and the lumen backend sends a Guzzle request for password grant to the sso server's /oauth/token. But the response is an error saying

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'licensing.oauth_clients'
>   doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `o (truncated...)

But 'licensing' is the db of my licensing project, not of sso, that has it's own. How and why tries sso query that db? Env files are correct, again, calling directly the sso project works fine. The very word 'licensing' doesn't even exist in sso project.

I'm really confused. Has anyone seen anything similar? Any ideas how and why this happens?

Comment: Can you show your project directories? Where are the various .env files located?

Comment: Each in their own project's folder. ' <docroot>/licensing-api/.env' for licensing, and '<docroot>/sso-api/.env' for sso.

Comment: Does both of the projects have distinct URLs or are they both running off the same domain?

Comment: Licensing is just running with localhost domain, sso has it;s own virtualhost setup.